# Gradle String index out of range: 0

Tags: gradle, gradlew

I'm documenting the Problem I had here as I was looking for the solution for quite a while before finding it. I hope it helps someone else as well...

I had the problem that whenever I executed any gradle task with Gradle 2.14.x i got the Exception `String index out of range: 0`. Everything was working fine with Gradle 2.12.x.

The debug output wasn't very helpful either:

```
$ gradle compileJava --debug
...
18:39:40.880 [INFO] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Starting Build
18:39:40.880 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Gradle user home: /home/olivier/.gradle
18:39:40.881 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Current dir: /home/olivier/Workspace/my-project
18:39:40.881 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Settings file: null
18:39:40.881 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Build file: null
18:39:40.882 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.buildsrc.BuildSourceBuilder] Starting to build the build sources.
18:39:40.882 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.buildsrc.BuildSourceBuilder] Gradle source dir does not exist. We leave.
18:39:40.882 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradlePropertiesLoader] Found env project properties: []
18:39:40.883 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradlePropertiesLoader] Found system project properties: []
18:39:40.884 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor] Timing: Processing settings took: 0.001 secs
18:39:40.885 [INFO] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Settings evaluated using settings file '/home/olivier/Workspace/my-project/settings.gradle'.
18:39:40.885 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Project : - Transitioning model element '<root>' from state Registered to Created
18:39:40.886 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Project : - Transitioning model element '<root>' to state Discovered.
18:39:40.886 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Project : - Transitioning model element '<root>' to state Created.
18:39:40.887 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Project : - Registering model element 'tasks' (hidden = false)
18:39:40.888 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Project : - Transitioning model element 'tasks' from state Registered to Created
18:39:40.888 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Project : - Running model element 'tasks' rule action Project.<init>.tasks()
18:39:40.888 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Project : - Mutating tasks using Project.<init>.tasks()
18:39:40.889 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Project : - Transitioning model element 'tasks' to state Discovered.
18:39:40.889 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Project : - Running model element 'tasks' rule action Project.<init>.tasks()
18:39:40.890 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Project : - Mutating tasks using Project.<init>.tasks()
18:39:40.890 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Project : - Transitioning model element 'tasks' to state Created.
18:39:40.892 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Project : - Registering model element 'serviceRegistry' (hidden = true)
18:39:40.893 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Project : - Registering model element 'buildDir' (hidden = true)
18:39:40.893 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Project : - Registering model element 'projectIdentifier' (hidden = true)
18:39:40.894 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Project : - Registering model element 'extensionContainer' (hidden = true)
18:39:40.894 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Project : - Registering model element 'fileOperations' (hidden = true)
18:39:40.894 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Project : - Registering model element 'sourceDirectorySetFactory' (hidden = true)
18:39:40.895 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Project : - Registering model element 'taskFactory' (hidden = true)
18:39:40.895 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Project : - Registering model element 'instantiator' (hidden = true)
18:39:40.896 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Project : - Registering model element 'typeConverter' (hidden = true)
18:39:40.896 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Project : - Registering model element 'nodeInitializerRegistry' (hidden = true)
18:39:40.896 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Project : - Registering model element 'structBindingsStore' (hidden = true)
18:39:40.897 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Project : - Registering model element 'proxyFactory' (hidden = true)
18:39:40.897 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Project : - Registering model element 'schemaStore' (hidden = true)
18:39:40.898 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.ProjectPropertySettingBuildLoader] Looking for project properties from: /home/olivier/Workspace/my-project/gradle.properties
18:39:40.898 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.ProjectPropertySettingBuildLoader] project property file does not exists. We continue!
18:39:40.899 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
18:39:40.899 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
18:39:40.899 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
18:39:40.899 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
18:39:40.900 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] String index out of range: 0
18:39:40.900 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
18:39:40.900 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
18:39:40.900 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. 
18:39:40.900 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] 
18:39:40.901 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
18:39:40.901 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] 
18:39:40.901 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] Total time: 0.635 secs
...
```

What I read from different posts accross the internet was that it was due to a syntax error in my properties files. But even after completely emptying those I couldn't get Gradle to run.

Answer (score 0):

The problem did actually occur in one of my properties files: `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` contained the string `:::properties` which I had copy and pasted by error from a documentation.